# Specify slImplementationName in tomcat connector

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, cryptography

I want to specify th slImplementationName class name in tomcat(version 8) connector so that the default order in java.security is not considered for SSL handshake part.

From tomcat documentation:-

> "The class name of the SSL implementation to use. If not specified,
>   the default of org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEImplementation will
>   be used which wraps JVM's default JSSE provider. Note that the JVM can
>   be configured to use a different JSSE provider as the default"

But this does not specify the implementing class from java that can be used with this attribute.

```
While trying to start tomcat by chnaging the attribut i am getting exception:-

06-Jun-2016 12:05:15.639 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-9443]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-9443]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:567)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:576)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:599)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:962)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Error loading SSL Implementation com.sun.security.sasl.Provider :java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.security.sasl.Provider cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLImplementation
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLImplementation.getInstance(SSLImplementation.java:75)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
        ... 13 more
```

I have tried using "com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider" and "com.sun.security.sasl.Provider", with no luck.

Any pointer will be very helpful.

Comment: SASL is a completely different protocol from SSL/TLS, so using SASL software to do SSL would be like using a sewing machine to bake a cake. That said, I concur with @beckyang's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class of `sslImplementationName` must extend `org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLImplementation`. So Exception is thrown when you specify a class which does not satisfy this condition.

Since your intention is changing the default order of **Cryptographic Service Provider**. You should override security configuration per JVM instance. Make sure `security.overridePropertiesFile=true` in `$JRE_HOME/lib/security/java.security`.

Then modify Tomcat startup command and add system property:

> -Djava.security.properties=_path_to_your_config_

For Java8, it could append or override the settings in `$JRE_HOME/lib/security/java.security`. For older version, it will completely override all settings.